# Spring-data-mongodb + playframework + guice

Tags: spring, playframework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm into using sprig data mongodb with the playframework application because of simplicity and high productivity spring-data has, but @Autowired doesn't work and i get [NullPointerException: null], i don't know how to manually wire it, and can't find a solution online, please can anyone help me with the situation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: would please just completely tell me how to use spring-data-mongodb with playframework